Creating new UUIDs while preserving relationships in JSON schema
I'm creating an export/import mechanism for some of our related DB models in JSON format. We are already using UUIDs for primary/foreign keys. Part of this mechanism will be a "clone" function, which should take an object and all related objects and create news rows in the DB while preserving the relationships, which will require creating new IDs over the old ones.
A plaintext find-and-replace process should work just fine for this: find everything that looks like a UUID, and then go one by one replacing each with a new UUID across the whole file. Our case doesn't require it, but in some scenarios it could be necessary to filter out and NOT replace some UUIDs (i.e. ones that refer to external objects in the DB not included in the export).
Is there any tool or process better suited for this requirement?
